# Flash file is not working in IE

Tags: flash, file

If we set flash palyer source as src='videos/getflashfile.aspx?videoid=1291'(getflashfile.aspx file gives us the actual file which is stored in database.Url is generating the file correctly) it is not working in IE , but the same working fine in Firefox. If we the souce as path from application(file system) it is working fine in all browsers.

If we set as external url it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post how you are embedding it? If the url is generated fine this is more likely to be a problem with how this is displayed in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the swf off in some database I would assume you are not setting the mime type properly in the getflashfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is the response header content-type set correctly? ie. application/x-shockwave-flash